# Find the value of p in the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\left(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}\right)\cdot\left(y+\sqrt{y^{2}+1}\right)=p$ then $x+y=?$

**Alternatives:**

a) $\frac{p-1}{p}$

b) $\frac{p-1}{2p}$

c) $\frac{p-1}{\sqrt{p}}$

d) $\frac{p}{2}$

e) $\frac{\sqrt{p}}{2}$

I try:

$x + \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{p}{y + \sqrt{y^2+1}} \therefore x + \sqrt{x^2+1} = \frac{p \cdot (y - \sqrt{y^2+1})}{y^2 - y^2 - 1} \therefore \\\\ x + \sqrt{x^2+1} = p \cdot (\sqrt{y^2+1} - y$

$y + \sqrt{y^2+1} = \frac{p}{x + \sqrt{x^2+1}} \therefore y + \sqrt{y^2+1} = \frac{p \cdot (x - \sqrt{x^2+1})}{x^2-x^2-1} \therefore \\\\ y + \sqrt{y^2+1} = p \cdot (\sqrt{x^2+1} - x)$

$x + \sqrt{x^2+1} + y + \sqrt{y^2+1} = p\sqrt{y^2+1} - p \cdot (x+y) + p \sqrt{x^2+1} \therefore \\\\ 
(x+y) + p \cdot (x+y) = p \cdot (\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}) - (\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}) \therefore \\\\ x+y = \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}) \cdot (p-1)}{p+1}, p \neq -1????$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried this but I can not get the answer.

Comment: I tried using $x=\tan\alpha$ and $y=\tan\beta$ but can't see hope

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to a problem like this is to pick convenient values for $x$ and $y$ and just plug in.  If you take $x=y=1$ we get $p=(1+\sqrt 2)^2=3+2\sqrt 2$ and $x+y=2$.  Just plug $p$ into each choice and see what works.  You are trusting the problem setter to have it true for all $x$ and $y$.  d and e are out immediately as they will not yield a rational result.  It would be a better problem to prove the formula works for all $x,y$, but that wouldn't give a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my first choice is to plug random $x$ and $y$ in  the equation and see which of the options follow. Let's take a look:

Choose $x=1,y=1$, then you will see that $p=(1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})=3+2\sqrt{2}$.

Since we have put  $x=1,y=1$ hence $x+y=2$. Let's look at the options one by one:

$1. \frac{p-1}{p}=\frac{2(1+\sqrt{2})}{3+2\sqrt{2}}\ne 2$

$2. \frac{p-1}{2p}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})}{3+\sqrt{2}}\ne2$ .

$3. \frac{p-1}{\sqrt{p}}=\frac{2(1+\sqrt{2})}{1+\sqrt{2}}=2=x+y$. Cheers ...

Take a look at the other options and you will find that they are not possible too.

So, option $3$ is correct.

Comment: I understood but i have a doubt. For any chosen value of x and y is the alternative C true? If I did not have the alternatives I would have got the solution?

Comment: For example for x=3 and y = 5 --> x+y = 8 and the alternative c = 7,7. For x=1 and y=2 x+y = 3 altenative c=3,16???